# Use Python to connect to SQLServer query in a loop, showing that the connection is successful but there is no query result

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

Let me first introduce the background of my problem.

```
pymssql version:
C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>pip show pymssql
Name: pymssql
Version: 2.2.7
Summary: DB-API interface to Microsoft SQL Server for Python. (new Cython-based version)
Home-page:
Author: Damien Churchill
Author-email: damoxc@gmail.com
```

and my code like following:

```py
def QueryTaskLotSatus(taskId, lotNo):
connect = pymssql.connect('192.168.5.15','sa','13234325','MyData')

if connect:
    print(connect)
    print("connect success")
cursor = connect.cursor()

#设置变量
task_id = taskId
lot_no = lotNo

#query = "SELECT * FROM TaskStatus WHERE TaskId=%s AND LotNo=%s AND (Status=0 OR Status=3)"
query = "SELECT TaskId, Status,StatusMessage, LotNo FROM TaskStatus WHERE TaskId=%s AND LotNo=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (task_id, lot_no))
print()
row = cursor.fetchone()
status = 5
while row:
    print(row)
    status = row[1]
    # print(row[1])
    # print(type(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.close()
connect.close()
return status
```

When I try to query some information in sql server at a loop, code may like this:

```py
for userId, taskLots in userDict.items():
    waiting_count = 0
    executing_count = 0
    if userId not in result:
        result[userId] = {'userId': userId, 'waittingTaskLot': [], 'executingTaskLot': []}
    user_count += 1
    for taskLot in taskLots:
        taskId, lotNo = str(taskLot).strip().split(',')
        try:
            status = QueryTaskLotSatus(taskId, lotNo)
            if status == 0:
                logging.info("success to process userId: " + str(userId) + "this user order: " + str(user_count) + "executingTaskCount: "+ str(executing_count))
                result[userId]['executingTaskLot'].extend(taskLot)
                executing_count += 1
            if status == 3:
                logging.info("success to process userId: " + str(userId) + "this user order: " + str(user_count) + "waitingTaskCount: " + str(waiting_count))
                result[userId]['waittingTaskLot'].extend(taskLot)
                waiting_count += 1
        except Exception as ex:
            write_tasklot(str(taskLot))
            logging.error("call sqlserver error: " + str(ex))
            continue
        time.sleep(1)
```

Then finally, sometimes I get the result from database, sometime it shows 'connect success', but can't get any information, the pics like following:

[image: Output result]

Comment: Are you sure there is always valid data matching that criteria? Why not do something to log a status 5 return?

Comment: yes, I use native sql to query according to the same conditions, and the data can be found out; it does not seem to be a problem with the data

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop with no break or exit condition with a duplicate assignment of `row`?

Comment: I agree with @JonSG that this is a data issue given the *sometimes* result. Print out the parameters and check if data truly exists. Show us the *native sql*. Only you know and see your data not us!

Comment: i agree with @JonSG too. do something to log an `else` status

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is indeed a data issue, That you all.